# New Lenovo Laptop - No WiFi, Touchpad or Touchscreen

Tags: wireless, touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

I've just changed from a MS Surface Laptop 3 to a Lenovo Flex 5 14 (Ryzen 7530U). After installing both Ubuntu 22.04 and Kubuntu 22.04, I'm having issues getting some of the hardware to work, most likely because of it being newer. Is there a fairly straightforward way to install these missing drivers? I have been using Ubuntu for a while, but I never had any issues with drivers before changing my laptop. Currently, I'm attached to a homeplug using a USB network adapter. Not ideal, but at least I'm able to install updates and hopefully a driver fix!

Laptop - IdeaPad Flex 5 14ABR8
WiFi Adapter - Realtek RTL8852BE **Resolved! Thanks to a post by @Jeremy31 [Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2481218&p=14120315#post14120315)**
Touchpad - Unknown
Touchscreen - Unknown

Edit: Oddly enough, Bluetooth seems to be working.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b852
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5413 (rev 03)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barcelo (rev c5)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
04:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
04:00.7 Signal processing controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/Renoir Sensor Fusion Hub
```

Comment: Newest hardware tends to work best with newest OS. Have you tried 22.04

Comment: Hi David. My mistake. It is actually 22.04. Sorry about that!

Comment: NP of course you have updated the question.

Comment: Yes I have corrected it to show the right version. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've now managed to get the touchpad working by downgrading the kernel to 5.19.0. The touchscreen is also working, but only single gesture mode it seems.

I also managed to get the WiFi working. I did this by installing the correct Linux Realtek driver available from Github. In my case, it was rtw8852be-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb.

The complete list of Realtek drivers can be found here:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

Hopefully this will save someone else some pain :-)